# Disable input field with CSS - prevent keyboard manipulation

Tags: css

I use quantity input field for product and don't want to allow any interaction with it:

```
<input id="product-qty" type="number">
```

My CSS is the following:

```
#product-qty {
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

But it's not enough, when I TAB, I can select quantity field and then do any keyboard entry I please. I can accept selecting quantity field, maybe it's even good accessibility-wise, but can't allow to enter or remove anything.

I know how to solve it with JavaScript, what I want is to know whether it's possible with CSS only and if yes - how to do it.

[Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/x6yLe0kp/)

Comment: Why not just make it `readonly`?

Comment: `readonly` changes element's html, what will require JavaScript in my case, I guess I will finally be forced to do so, however even with `readonly` and all CSS rules in my original post, I can still select input with tab and as I mentioned I can accept highlight around the field, but it also highlights quantity.

Comment: @RyszardJędraszyk readonly is CSS pseudo-class. why would it require JavaScript in your case?

Comment: Don't I need to place readonly within <input> tag?  About input value's highlight, I solved it with this: `.readonly-qty::selection { background: transparent; } readonly-qty::-moz-selection { background: transparent; }`, I guess I'll need JS to add class `readonly-qty` anyway, but at least it works and with `readonly` I don't need `pointer-events: none;`, so title displays correctly without workarounds.

Comment: @RyszardJędraszyk You never mentioned you want to highlight the input value as well. You can do so by just selecting the input value as follows:  input[value] { color: blue;}

Comment: You are correct, I never mentioned it :) I didn't want to highlight it, but to remove highlight of value when input box is focused with TAB, I wrote solution in my comment.

Answer (score 1):

As @j08691 mentioned, you can use readonly to prevent any interaction with the input.

```
<input readonly id="product-qty" type="number">
```